# setid and getid? Error putIntArray?

Tags: android

```
for(int i=0; i<value1; i++) {
            addAnsMCQ = new EditText(this);
            AnswerRG.addView(addAnsMCQ, 1);
            addAnsMCQ.setId(i);
```

Hi guys, i start coding android and have seen the setId method but how to get the id? I use the findViewById but cannot. Please help me thank you?

My second question is?
Button create;

```
TextView gotAnswer, NoAnsV;
    EditText NoQues, NoAnswer;
    Integer data[] = new Integer[]{};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.manualask);     
        NoQues = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.NoQues);
        NoAnswer = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.NoAnsw);
        create = (Button) findViewById (R.id.create);
        create.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        switch (v.getId()){     
        case R.id.create:
            Intent intent = new Intent(Manual.this, MCQSample.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            data[0] = Integer.parseInt(NoQues.getText().toString());    

            data[1] = Integer.parseInt(NoAnswer.getText().toString());  
            b.putIntArray("key", data);
            intent.putExtras(b);    
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            break;
```

How to put the putIntArray. I continuously get the error even cchange the parameter data[] etc. Pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I continuously get the error even cchange the parameter data[] etc.

The declaration of `data` should be:

```
int data[] = new int[2];
```

In your declaration (`Integer data[] = new Integer[]{};`) you declare an array with size 0, and later you try to access cells 0 and 1 which doesn't exist.

Comment: The first one is ok but the second is wrond, it still identify error. :-(

Comment: Oppps, it works so nice. I own you a apologize dude!!

Comment: @CaoLinhTruong - if an answer for your question is helpful and satisfies you, please consider accepting it - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work